# php: json_decode containing HTML fails to decode

Tags: php, html, json

I need to use a customer's API for loading JSON which only contains something like:

```
{"html" : "foo"}
```

The API is being used from other services so I'm pretty sure it's valid.

However, when trying to decode it using json_decode i'm always getting an empty string which means it's not valid. I found out i need to "fix" the JSON-String by replacing:

```
$json = str_replace("\\>", "\\\\>", $json); // \> = invalid json
```

It works mainly on each request but not on certain others but it's very tricky to debug and i can't imagine that replacing is the proper method.
How would i do it the easy way for converting the json string into a valid one?

thanks

Comment: You show what the JSON should contain, but can you add a sample of the values which you get before the `str_replace()`?

Comment: We can't help without an example. Probably this is not a valid JSON, but the problematic bit is recoverable for your other service.

Comment: are you sure that you have problems with html? did you use `json_last_error`?

Comment: unfortunately the json is huge so i can't debug / tell what's wrong.. json_last_error says 4 - syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Ok i could find out what's wrong:

The HTML contains backslashes in the closing tags, for example `<br\>`
You need to replace them like this:

```
$json = str_replace("\\>", "\\\\>", $json);
```

and json_decode will work